# What is the general solution to $2 \cos^2 x-\cos x=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

What is the general solution to this trig equation?

$$2 \cos^2 x-\cos x=0$$

Thanks.

Comment: What is going on? The question is massively upvoted (although it has zero context), as are some answers (even some that are wrong), for no valid reason that I can fathom...

Answer (score 19):

To make it easier to visualise and solve, you can substitute $u=\cos{x}$.
$$2\cos^2{x}-\cos{x}=0$$
$$2u^2-u=0$$
From here, you can either use the quadratic formula or factorise. I chose to factorise:
$$u(2u-1)=0$$
Hence we have the solutions $u=0,\frac{1}{2}$.
Now, we solve the equations resulting from our substitution $u=\cos{x}$:
$$\cos{x}=0 \tag{1}$$
$$\cos{x}=\frac{1}{2} \tag{2}$$

For equation $(1)$, we obtain:`
$$x=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$$
For equation $(2)$, we obtain:
$$x=2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{3}$$
And
$$x=2k\pi-\frac{\pi}{3}$$
Where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Hence, our general solution is:
$$x=\begin{cases} \frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi \\ 2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{3} \\ 2k\pi-\frac{\pi}{3} \end{cases}$$

Comment: The key thing for OP to understand is that one can't just divide thru by cos(x) as this would lose the first solution cos(x)=0 .  The u substitution is brilliant as it helps prep students for the calculus to come.

Comment: Haha, you have been quite active now haven't you?

Comment: I must applaud you for making it to the first page : http://math.stackexchange.com/users

Answer (score 13):

**hint**: $2\cos^2 x -\cos x = \cos x(2\cos x - 1)=0$

Answer (score 9):

Notice that $$2 \cos^2 x-\cos x=0\implies 2\cos^2x=\cos x$$

So either $\cos x=0$ or $\cos x=\frac{1}{2}$.

Now find general solution

Answer (score 5):

$$2\cos^2(x) - \cos(x) = 0 \implies \cos(x)(2\cos(x) - 1) = 0$$

For what $x$ is $\cos(x) = 0, \frac{1}{2}$? There are only 2 solutions that form all distinct solutions; all others are $2k\pi{}$ away from them

[Have a look](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_right_triangle#30.C2.B0.E2.80.9360.C2.B0.E2.80.9390.C2.B0_triangle)

Comment: not correct - the solutions for cos(x) = 0 are more common than that

Comment: There are * three* solutions that form all distinct solutions,  namely $2n\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{3}$ and the solutions you neglect, $\pi n + \frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

$2\cos^2 x-\cos x=0$

$\implies \cos x(2\cos x-1)=0$

Either

$\cos x=0$

$\implies x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}\pm 2n\pi$

Or

$2\cos x-1=0$

$\implies \cos x=\dfrac{1}{2}$

$\implies x=\dfrac{\pi}{3}\pm 2n\pi$

where
 $n \in Z$

Comment: Your missing some solutions.

Comment: also   $-{\pi}/3+...$

Comment: You don't need to write $\pm$... Just let $n$ be negative as well. Moreover, you need to include $2n\pi - \frac{\pi}3$